# How to return from root log-in to my user log-in?

Tags: command-line, su

I'm using SuSE Linux Enterprise and I know that there is a command

```
su root
```

for changing to root log-in. But what about the other way around? If I prefer to return to my user account, how to do it?

Comment: You just exit the root shell...

Comment: Run `exit` or hit Ctrl+D.

Comment: To become root, you can just use `su`, instead of `su root`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want to return to your account, you have 3 ways:

```
exit
CTRL +D
logout
```

If you want to change to another user, you can use `su` again.

```
su differentuser
```

Answer (score 2):

Just type `exit` to exit the shell.

Answer (score 2):

```
su username
```

If you want to load environment variables,

```
su - username
```

Answer (score -2):

Type exit, logout, and ctrl D. All of these only exit the terminal and does not logout of the root account. Additionally, when executing the terminal window again it is still logged in as root. This is through THM (TryHackMe)

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note that your answer seems to reiterate what was already stated in the [accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/129099/377345). You may want to consider expanding it so that the difference to that answer becomes more visible; otherwise it would be best placed as a comment to that answer (once you have sufficient reputation).